# Templates and ODR

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

The question is about the C++ documentation and standard documentation. Is in the following code the variable `x` odr-used?

```
extern int x;
template<class T> T f() { return x; }
```

It seems to me it is not used, bud where it is stated in documents? (there is the statement, that appearance `x` in expression is odr-use, but...)

Answer (score 1):

It is odr-used.  [basic.def.odr]/2:

> An expression is *potentially evaluated* unless it is an unevaluated operand or a subexpression thereof.

Thus the expression `x` is *potentially evaluated*.

[basic.def.odr]/4:

> A variable `x` whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression `ex` is *odr-used* by `ex` unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion ([conv.lval]) to `x` yields a constant expression ([expr.const]) [...]

We can stop here. Applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `x` does not yield a constant expression.

This violation of the ODR does not require a diagnostic ([basic.def.odr]/10):

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline
>   function or variable that is odr-used in that program outside of a
>   discarded statement; no diagnostic required.

---

Even assuming for the sake of argument that `f` does not odr-use `x` until/unless a specialization is generated, it still won't help the program, because the program is also ill-formed NDR if "no valid specialization can be generated for a template" ([temp.res]/8), and since every valid specialization of `f` undoubtedly odr-uses `x`, no valid specialization can be generated if a definition of `x` is not present in the program.

Comment: What then about instantiation of templates when they are used? If x were a template or static data member of a class template... It should be then instantiated. But I don't found compilers to do this...